buildProxy() of CommonAPI gives memory fault
I have an fidl file for commonAPI like shown below:

interface DeviceManager manages Device {
    version { major 1 minor 0 }

    method openDevice {
        in {
            String name
        }
        out {
            Int32 result
        }
    }

    method closeDevice {
        in {
            String name
        }
        out {
            Int32 result
        }
    }
}

interface Device {
    version { major 1 minor 0 }

    method startDevice {
        out {
            Int32 result
        }
    }
    method stopDevice {
        out {
            Int32 result
        }
    }
}

Using this I generate the src-gen of required for CommonAPI/vsomeip to work.
I build server and client both.
Server works fine. But in the client I get a memory fault.
Let me show you parts of the client code:
  std::shared_ptr<DeviceManagerProxy<>> managerProxy =
      runtime->buildProxy<DeviceManagerProxy>(domain, instance,
                                                    connectionIdClient);
  int32_t retryTimes = 0;
  while (!managerProxy->isAvailable() &&
         retryTimes++ < 10) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
  }
  if (!managerProxy->isAvailable()) {
    LOGE("create DeviceManager proxy failed");
    return nullptr;
  }

So here we built the object in client for calling functions of the manager and if I make a call to the server's manager's openDevice function, it successfully executes openDevice function in the server and comes back with proper return value.

managerProxy->openDevice(device, callStatus, result, &info); // successful


Now After this I build proxy for managed object:
  std::shared_ptr<DeviceProxy<>> deviceProxy =
      managerProxy->getProxyManagerDevice().buildProxy<DeviceProxy>(
          device); // memory fault



Now here I get the memory fault. If I look at the logs I see:

2019-01-01 00:01:02.628902 [info] local_uds_client_endpoint_impl::receive_cbk Error: End of file
2019-01-01 00:01:02.628902 [info] routing_manager_impl::handle_client_error Client 0x100 handles a client error(101)
2019-01-01 00:01:02.628912 [info] Application/Client 0101 is deregistering.
2019-01-01 00:01:02.628922 [info] Client [100] is closing connection to [101]
2019-01-01 00:01:02.628922 [info] RELEASE(0101): [1235.ffff]
Memory fault


